# how to create a binary file

Tags: java, syntax, binary

I am trying to do this assignment.

```
(Sum all the integers in a binary data file)
 * create a binary data file named Exercise17_03.dat
 * has been created and its data are created using writeInt(int)
 * in DataOutputStream. The file contains an unspecified number
 * of integers. Write a program to find the sum of the integers.
```

my code:

```
package loan;

import java.io.*;


public class Exercise17_03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Get the file for this exercise
        File file = new File("src/text files/Exercise17_03.dat");

        // if file doesn't exist create the file and write a random number of integers
        if (!file.exists() || true) {
            try (DataOutputStream out =
                         new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)))) {

                int random = (int) (Math.random() * 200);

                for (int i = 0; i < random; i++) {
                    out.writeInt((int)(Math.random() * 200));
                }
            }
        }

        // Read the file and display the sum
        try (DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)))) {

            int sum = 0;
            int count = input.available() / 4;
            System.out.println(count);
            while (count > 0) {
                sum += input.readInt();
                count--;
            }
            System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
        }


    }
}
```

for some reason i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\text files\Exercise17_03.dat (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at loan.Exercise17_03.main(Exercise17_03.java:24)
```

I do not completely understand what the syntax is telling me. Can someone help me understand so I do not run into the problem in the future. Also in this creating a binary file. It does not look right to me, thank you.

I am not sure why the question is marked as a duplicate. It is different. This is a question about my individual assignment and what is wrong with my code. I dont see how it is a duplicate.

Comment: Check directory `src/text files/` exists.

Comment: what part of `java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\text files\Exercise17_03.dat (The system cannot find the path specified)` is not self explanatory?

Comment: See also: [How to create a file and write to a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

I would guess that either the `src` directory or its `text files` subdirectory does not exist **relative to the current directory the runtime is executing from**, since the `FileNotFoundException` is being thrown from the `FileOutputStream` constructor.